# jQuery Ajax html/script transmission

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a text box where users can enter  html type code into. I have a AJAX jquery method which sends this to the controller. However, I notice that the controller is not being invoked if i send '< script > some text here < / script >' type code via jquery Ajax. The controller has a **string** type for the parameter. What should I do on the client/server side to allow the code to be sent across successfully?

client side code:

```
$("#HtmlID").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            data
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        success: function (text) {

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {

        }
    });
});
```

TIA

Comment: How about encoding data before sending it and decoding at the controller level? Try urlnecode or base64 for example.

Comment: Well I have one field in the data: { field.HTML } where this needs to be encoded. How do i go about just encoding this rather than everything thats in the data: {}.

Comment: If you really need to avoid encoding anything you may use regular expression to replace <script> tags.

Comment: allowing users to enter inline script or script tags is a huge security risk to your site!!!

Comment: I think it will be simpler to use a dropdown select element or radio buttons rather than an input element of type text, because that way you can narrow down the HTML type options. Of course, you would still need to validate the input before submission.

Comment: First, you have to figure out where it is being stopped. Certainly possible that the server-code you are using is sanitizing the data being passed in automagically. You can confirm this by looking at your browser network console to see what data the browser sent.